# Signal vs Exceptions vs Hardware Interrupts vs Traps

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, interrupt

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13380714/4390699) answer and I thought that I got a clear idea. But then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149217/4390699) answer is confusing me again.

Can somebody please give me a clear picture of the differences between Signal, exception, hardware interrupts and traps?

Moreover, I would like to know which among these **block CPU preemption** of the kernel code?

**Examples** would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

•**Interrupts** are generated by hardware for events external to the processor core.
These are asynchronous in nature which means the processor is unaware of when the interrupt will be generated. These are also called hardware interrupts. Example: interrupt generated by keyboard to type a character on screen, or the timer interrupt.

•**Exceptions**: Exceptions occur when the processor detects an error condition while executing an instruction and are classified as **faults**, **traps**, or **aborts** depending on the way they are reported and whether the instruction that caused the exception can be restarted without loss of program or task continuity. (Those technical terms are used on x86 at least, maybe other architectures or in general.)  Example: Divide by zero, or a page fault.

•**Traps**: are basically an instruction which tells the kernel to switch to kernel mode from user mode. Example: during a system call, a TRAP instruction would force kernel to execute the system call code inside kernel (kernel mode) on behalf of the process.
Trap is a kind of exception.
The x86 `int 0x80` "software interrupt" instruction is a trap, not like external interrupts.  x86 uses a single table of handlers for both interrupts and exceptions; other ISAs may also do that.

Some people use this term more generally, as a synonym for "exception".  e.g. you might say "MIPS `add` will trap on signed overflow, so compilers always use `addu`."

•**Signals**: signals are generated by kernel or by a process (`kill` system call). They are eventually managed by the OS kernel, which delivers them to the target thread/process. E.g. a divide by zero instruction would result in kernel delivering a SIGFPE signal (arithmetic exception) to the process that ran it.  (For example, the x86 #DE fault is handled by the kernel, generating a software SIGFPE for the current process.)

---

Related:

- [When an interrupt occurs, what happens to instructions in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902132/when-an-interrupt-occurs-what-happens-to-instructions-in-the-pipeline) - @Krazy Glew's answer also defines some terminology using Intel definitions.
- [Why are segfaults called faults (and not aborts) if they are not recoverable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396346/why-are-segfaults-called-faults-and-not-aborts-if-they-are-not-recoverable) - segfaults are a special case of page faults, which are normally recoverable.  And even an invalid page fault from user-space doesn't crash the kernel, so it's recoverable in that sense.

Comment: 1. Interrupts can be issued by hardware. 2. Exceptions aren't synchronous. 3. All things can trap to kernel. 4. Signals aren't always generated by the kernel (process-process signaling happens too).

Comment: @ynChen Good edit, but I think some of the technical terminology is x86-specific, like exceptions being either a fault, trap, or abort.  The question doesn't mention x86.  Does the Linux kernel use those terms internally for different kinds of exceptions, or do other architectures agree on that terminology?  For now I'm going to edit to mention x86 here.